# How to mock constructor using Mockito

Tags: mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito, spy

I have a question regarding one of the feature of mockito. On several blogs I have read that mocking constructor is not possible through mockito.

For one of my test case, currently it is done through powermockito but I want to remove it due to some performance issues.

Currently the code looks something like this:

Actual class:

```
public class TestClass {
    private ClassB classB;

    public TestClass(ClassB classB) {
       this.classB = classB;
    }
}
```

In my test class, I have code like this:

```
TestClass testClass = Mockito.mock(TestClass.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(TestClass.class).withArguments(this.classB)
    .thenReturn(testClass);
```

So could anyone suggest me, is there any other way possible by which I can achieve the same thing through mockito? Also on some blogs, I found that injection a public method with constructor of the class inside and then mocking that method can do the trick. But wanted to know all other options to analyze.

Thanks

-Sam

Comment: Can you share more of your `TestClass`? What exactly are you trying to achieve? If it's mocked anyway, why do you care about the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if that can help you.

```
class MyClass {

            private final MySecondClass clazz;

            MyClass(MySecondClass clazz) {
                this.clazz = clazz;
            }

            public boolean executeDoSomething() {
                return clazz.doSomething();
            }
        }
```

And in the test you could mock the inner class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
        public class MyClassTest {
            @Test
            public void MyClassTest() {
                MySecondClass mockedPerformer = Mockito.mock(MySecondClass.class);
                MyClass clazz = new MyClass(mockedPerformer);
                clazz.executeDoSomething();
            }
        }
```

I hope this helps you.